# How to connect Node.js application to MongoDB Atlas Cloud using certificate with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose

I try to connect to MongoDB Cloud database. I chose authentication with X509 certificate. I can connect to with mongosh or MongoDB Compass.

For example:

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://somewhere.d3m3rrv.mongodb.net/macau-game?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509" --apiVersion 1 --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile rootCA.pem
```

works well but with Node.js:

```
mongoose.connect(config.db.mongoUri, {
    tls: true,
    authMechanism: 'MONGODB-X509',
    authSource: "$external",
    tlsCAFile: `rootCA.pem`
});

logger.info("Trying to connect to database " + config.db.mongoUri)

mongoose.connection
    .once("open", () => {
        logger.info("MongoDB Connection success");
    })
    .on("error", (error) => {
        logger.error("MongoDB Connection to " + config.db.mongoUri + "failed");
    })
```

I get this error:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Connection.openUri (/root/app/dist/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:807:32)
```

IP address is added to whitelist, .pem file chmod is set to 400. Please help me.

UPDATE:
I updated mongoose connect options. Current version:

```
mongoose.connect(config.db.mongoUri, {
    ssl: true,
    sslCert: credentials,
    sslKey: credentials,
});
```

Server connects to the database, but when try load any data I get this error:

```
MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [my-db.chats]
    at Connection.onMessage (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:450:20)
```

On the MongoDB Cloud database access cnofiguration user of this cert has privilages to read and write to any database.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but showed up as the first entry after I searched for this same problem. I solved it by simply putting in a whole connection string which worked in MongoDB Compass:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://<username>@<mongourl>/?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority&tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=./mongodb.pem`, {
    dbName: '<dbname>',
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false, // optional
    useCreateIndex: true, // We use this from the entrypoint in the docker-compose file
})
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
});

export default mongoose;
```

I also ran into this error:

```
MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [my-db.chats]
    at Connection.onMessage (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:450:20)
```

I solved this by ensuring the user that I created the certificate for had the correct role in Atlas. You can change this by going to Database Access -> Database Users -> Edit -> Built-in Role and selecting the correct role.